# Gerar txt com formato padrão

Tags: c#, winforms, txt

tudo bem?

Eu preciso gerar um arquivo txt com um formato padrão como abaixo:

```
D00000002       200014002154129   $9997 7720 0000 0012 *           12/19        *CLARICE LISPECTOR       *0014-00  215412-9       *     %B9997772000000012^CLARICE LISPECTOR
```

Serão varias linhas e todas elas terão que ter o mesmo tamanho e espaço entre os dados.
Qual a melhor forma de gerar esses espaços (precisar ser espaço mesmo, como caracter em branco) e garantir que o arquivo está ok?

Obrigado.

Comment: defina o que exatamente quer dizer com o mesmo tamanho e mesmo espaço

Comment: Se calhar é melhor colocar na sua questão o tamanho e formato de cada um dos elementos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar os metodos `String.PadLeft` ou `String.PadRight`

```
string str = "Lorem ipsum";
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(15));  // "    Lorem ipsum"
Console.WriteLine(str.PadRight(5));  // "Lorem ipsum   "
```

Comment: Olá Danilo, vou testar aqui.. Obrigado! ;)